# how to send a complete (.txt,.doc) file in java

Tags: java, network-programming

i am making a client server program in java, a portion of which requires to send
a complete file (.txt or .docx) file from client to server. I am not sure how to do
it, i have tried using this webpage
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html
, but it seems that it don't work correctly 
in form + multi-threaded application, is there any other way to send a complete
file from client to server?

Any help/suggestions are appreciated...

regards
usama

Comment: the first question you need to answer for yourself, is if you need to send that file through http, and the server is an application server. Depending on that answer, you would do it in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you have to read the file on your client application, open an OutputStream to the server, and write the contents of the file to this stream.
On the server you read from the other end of the stream.

Depending on your architecture, you either will use a new socket-pair for the file transfer, or somehow embed it into your existing communication protocol.

Comment: hi Paulo! thanks for the answer, ur advice is really very helpful, i will try to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a Messaging Application for your purpose. I would recommend using JMS. I personally use [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) . If this does not suit your need then try out [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/). It would abstract you from the Network Programming.

Comment: hi Abhishek! , thanks for ur reply, i will explore ur suggested links, but i was wandering that is it possible to do it without using any external libraries, ? just by using the framework of java, i just found that java serialization can be helpful?

Comment: Yes Java Serialization would be better if you only wish to use Core Java components and no Web Components.